# Is there some built in facility in Python that provides a set with a maximum size and that deletes oldest entries after max size is reached?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, fifo

I have a very specific need: a set-like implementation (for O(1) member checking) which allows a maximum number of elements to be added to it, and that many have been added new items would cause the oldest (in the order they have been added to it) from being replaced / deleted. Say, FIFO / First In First Out.

Is there such a thing in Python, either built-in or in a library?

I searched but no luck...

My use case is that I have a steady number of hashes coming in, and I need to detect duplicates. But of course memory is limited and in my case older hashes have lesser value, so after adding new ones to this given set I would like its size to be capped, and older hashes to be replaced in this set as newer ones come in so that the size stays constant from that point on.

Any pointers will be very helpful, thank you!

Comment: You could probably implement something on top of [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque), which is effectively a FIFO list with a size limit.

Comment: You might want to look at the implementation of functooks.lru_cache. In uses a dictionary in which the values are both the actual value you want and a linked list of keys in LRU order.

Comment: The issue with deque is that lookups are expensive... I need to look up random items in it really fast (O(1) in this case). I'll take a look at `functooks.lru_cache` - thank you!

Comment: @EdyBourneYou can create your own type, that could use a `set` and `collections.deque` underneath the hood. It's, a pretty reasonable solution to this problem. The additional overhead of using a `set` with an auxiliary `collections.deque` is probably only a little more than 8 bytes per object.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Using both is the canonical solution for this problem. Add new elements to one end of the deque and to the set. Test existence of elements from the set. And if more than `n` elements are in, pop one element from the other end of the deque, and also from the set (once we known which one it is, thanks to the pop from deque)

Comment: Hi @chrslg - can you move your comment into an answer, so I can accept it? Thank you, that is very clever!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested, my comment in the form of an answer.

Using both is the canonical solution for this problem. Add new elements to one end of the deque and to the set. Test existence of elements from the set. And if more than n elements are in, pop one element from the other end of the deque, and also from the set (once we known which one it is, thanks to the pop from deque)

So, that would be something like

```py
from collections import deque
class FixedSizeSet:
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.N=N
        self.theSet=set()
        self.q=deque()

    def add(self, elt):
        if elt in self.theSet: return
        self.theSet.add(elt)
        self.q.append(elt)
        while len(self.q)>self.N:
            old=self.q.popleft()
            self.theSet.remove(old)

    def remove(self, elt):
        self.q.remove(elt)   # That the weak part. But your usage didn't mention any explicit remove. 
                             # That explicit remove is O(n)
                             # whereas the implicit one (the one that occurs because you added something) is O(1) 
        self.theSet.remove(elt)

    def __contains__(self, elt):
        return elt in self.theSet
            

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.theSet.__repr__()



s=FixedSizeSet(3)
s.add(1)
s.add(2)
s.add(3)
s.add(4)
1 in s
# False
2 in s
# True
4 in s 
# True
```

Cost of adding is indeed O(1), apparently: cost of adding n×10000 (so from n=10000 to n=10000000) elements to the `FixedSizeSet(10000)`

[image]

(The very fast ramp up at the beginning, which is reproducible, not just noise, comes from the fact that testing a set is not really O(1), even if python's doc says otherwise.)

But that is not surprising. Of course it is O(1), whatever the implementation, since the size is limited (once we've added N elements, it is always the same cost: cost of adding 1 more thing to a collection of N things, then removing 1 thing from a collection of N+1 things)

If multiply N (N≡the max size of the set) by 10, I get
[image]

So, it doesn't depend on N neither. Which is more interesting.

Comment: Nice implementaiton, and great thing posting the benchmarks. Follow some rbabling as I am not writting another anser (not right now, at least):

a really useful thing would have to bring elements that are "hit" back to the top. Maybe associating a dict with the keys being the desired keys, and last-access timestamp as values, and a linked list ordered by existing timestamps one can get O(Log(N)) for all operations. Implement the linked list in a "slotted" array, and keep the slot information  along with the timestamp in the first dict, should  allow for O(1)  for everything.

Comment: In fact, my first idea was to use a dict. And just a dict, without any set or deque. Because, since python 3.8 order of dict entries is guaranteed to be the order of adding (or 3.6, or 3.7, not exactly sure. In fact it was already the case before. But before it was just because implementation happened to be that way, but we were not supposed to rely on it. When, now, it is an official behavior). Plus, testing if a key is present in a dict is also O(1). So it was tempting to just use a dict. Add elt is `dic[elt]=stg`. Test if elt is in dict is `elt in dic`. And to remove first element when

Comment: we have reached `N`, it is just some `dic.pop(next(iter(dic)))`, which is guaranteed to be the oldest.

Comment: @jsbueno The only reason I did not post that kind of solution is because it is very slow. Adding to, or testing for a dic is O(1), sure. But a O(1) that cost more than a set + a deque. The only clear advantage (outside code simplicity) would have been memory. Not only there is 1 collection instead of 2. But a set alone is twice bigger in memory than a `{key:None}` dict.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest building a new class based on a set and adding as a deque member.  This will leverage most of the existing set functions for accessing the items.

```
from collections import deque
class FIFOset(set):

    def __init__(self,maxSize):
        super().__init__()
        self.maxSize  = maxSize
        self.addOrder = deque()
        
    def add(self,value):
        if value in self: return
        if len(self)==self.maxSize:        # max reached
            self.remove(self.addOrder[0])  # remove first added
        super().add(value)
        self.addOrder.append(value)
    
    def remove(self,value):               # removing 1st will be fast
        super().remove(value)             # others, not so much
        self.addOrder.remove(value)
```

output:

```
mySet = FIFOset(10)

for i in range(10):
    mySet.add(i)
print(mySet)
FIFOset({0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9})

for i in range(15,20):
    mySet.add(i)
print(mySet)
FIFOset({5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19})
```

Comment: In remove, why not `self.addOrder.popleft()` instead of `self.addOrder.remove(value)`?  Is it because your code works for any item to be deleted in the deque and not the FIFO value only? `remove` in the broadest sense.

Comment: Yes that was the idea.  Making the new class as flexible as a normal set while adding the FIFO behaviour.  Of course, there would be more work involved but that was intended to give the general direction.